# Hide the entire dropdown menu for a select element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to use a HTML select element, but disable the dropdown menu. I still want the user to be able to use the up/down arrows when focused on the element, but I don't want the menu to actually appear (I plan on replacing it due to low customizability).
Most sources I see suggest using `display: none` for the option elements, however that still leaves behind a little blank bar:
[image]
and this also will not allow the user to use up/down arrows to navigate the menu.

Is this possible while still using the form `select` element, without losing tab/arrow navigation abilities, with pure CSS? I want to use `select` for accessibility/form compatibility.

```css
select {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}
option {
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=1>Value 1</option>
  <option value=2>Value 2</option>
  <option value=3>Value 3</option>
  <option value=4>Value 4</option>
  <option value=5>Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you want to hide it while keeping the possibility of choosing an item using the arrow keys ?

Comment: @ths Precisely. For accessibility sake, I still want to be able to select values using arrow keys. I plan on replacing the dropdown menu with a completely custom one, so that's the only part I want to get rid of.
I find that setting `font-size: 0px` for the option elements hides them, but still allows the arrow keys to work. The issue of the black bar still appearing remains. I know this is OS-rendered, but I'm curious if it could be hidden completely.

Comment: *Accessibility*, did you think of mobile users, for example, and will they interact with the dropdown menu ?

Comment: @ths Yes! The idea is that the `<select>`'s default menu will show on mobile (because the browser's dropdown menus are probably the best thing on mobile) whereas on desktop the dropdown is hidden and replaced with a custom one.
I'm aware of JS ways to do this without using `<select>` (like lists, or even just divs) but I wanted to retain the accessibility and form aspects of `<select>` (such as tabbing and using arrows to navigate).

Answer (score 1):

The browser's default action is to focus the input and open the list

You need to `event.preventDefault()` opening action and then `focus()` the target element

```js
function handleclick(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.target.focus();
}
```

```css
select {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}
option {
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<select onmousedown="handleclick(event)">
  <option value=1>Value 1</option>
  <option value=2>Value 2</option>
  <option value=3>Value 3</option>
  <option value=4>Value 4</option>
  <option value=5>Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is nice and concise, and probably what I'll end up using. Though I will keep the question open for a while to see if anyone comes up with non-JS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a select element. If you want to have a custom menu, you can use a button/div along with some javascript. [Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_right) a nice example from W3S:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<h2>Aligned Dropdown Content</h2>
<p>Use <strong>float: right</strong> on the dropdown class to float the dropdown menu to the right, and <strong>right:0</strong> on the dropdown-content if you want the dropdown content to go from right to left.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

(PS: You might want to send a bug report to your browser if an option with display:none still leaves an outline)

Comment: Unfortunate, but I expected this to be the truth since that menu is OS-rendered. I guess I could program the accessibility features with JS.
Also, that isn't an option element, that's the padding for the dropdown menu. Same thing would appear if you used a `<select>` with no `<option>` children. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can modify the padding.

Comment: @JoshSilveous On Chrome at least, the padding of the options is automatically set to that of the "select" element.

Comment: Interesting, I'll play with this for a bit and test around with different browsers.